# Rewrite partial URL to specific page with .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Couldn't really figure out a title for this, so it's not the best, sorry.

I'm looking to rewrite URLs like this:

```
https://awesomechristianmusic.com/song-list?artist=dc-talk
```

To look like this:

```
https://awesomechristianmusic.com/dc-talk
```

Or for genres/topics:

```
https://awesomechristianmusic.com/song-list?genre=rock
https://awesomechristianmusic.com/song-list?topic=forgiveness
```

To look like this:

```
https://awesomechristianmusic.com/genre/rock
https://awesomechristianmusic.com/topic/forgiveness
```

Unfortunately, there seem to be some issues with my .htaccess file and I can't figure it out. Here's what I'm working with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=301]

# Remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# This is where I'm currently working
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /song-list?artist=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/genre/([^/]+)$ /song-list?genre=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/topic/([^/]+)$ /song-list?topic=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Redirect everything through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/(api|edit)/?.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [NC,L,QSA]

# long list of 301 redirects
```

Currently, the three rewrites I'm working on don't do anything. If I remove the slashes at the beginning of their regexes, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Any ideas what might be going wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Swap out these three rules:

```
# This is where I'm currently working
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /song-list?artist=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/genre/([^/]+)$ /song-list?genre=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/topic/([^/]+)$ /song-list?topic=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

To these three rules:

```
# If not /genre/* and not /topic/*
# Convert /dc-talk to /song-list?artist=dc-talk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/genre/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/topic/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ song-list?artist=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Convert /genre/rock to /song-list?genre=rock
RewriteRule ^genre/(.*)$ song-list?genre=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Convert /topic/forgivenessto /song-list?topic=forgiveness
RewriteRule ^topic/(.*)$ song-list?topic=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

You can view these rules in action here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=763f7107-f056-5ebe-ae0a-7f53a17b225a

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this breaks many of the other URLs on my site, for example `/dc-talk/what-if-i-stumble` (a song page) or even `/song-list` itself. Which actually raises a thought about why I might be getting 500 errors, come to think of it...

Comment: You will have to copy and paste all the other URL's to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/INSERT_URL_HERE/(.*)$ [NC]` and paste it before the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ song-list?artist=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` rule.

Comment: Sadly that really isn't a maintainable solution, since I'd prefer to not edit the .htaccess every time I add a song (usually 5 times a day or so).

Comment: Have you tried moving these rules down to very bottom of the .htaccess? That way all other rules will be checked first.

Comment: They're as low as they can go without putting them outside of the routing system, which defeats the purpose even more thoroughly.